# Android - Horizontal List View with arrows

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to make a Horizontal List View with two arrows, one to move on the left, one to move on the right.

I want those arrows to be displayed only when the scroll is too large to be displayed in one piece.

I've the following layout:

```
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/availability_ctx_right_col"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/availability_ctx_level1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#706969"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/availability_ctx_level1_left"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
                android:contentDescription="@string/left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/availability_ctx_level1_right"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"
                android:contentDescription="@string/right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <com.my.package.HorizontalListView
                android:id="@+id/availability_ctx_level1_list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/availability_ctx_level1_left"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/availability_ctx_level1_right" />

        </RelativeLayout >

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/availability_ctx_level2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#5a4f4f"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/availability_ctx_level2_left"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
                android:contentDescription="@string/left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/availability_ctx_level2_right"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"
                android:contentDescription="@string/right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <com.my.package.HorizontalListView
                android:id="@+id/availability_ctx_level2_list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/availability_ctx_level2_left"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/availability_ctx_level2_right" />

        </RelativeLayout >

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/availability_ctx_level3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#706969"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/availability_ctx_level3_left"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
                android:contentDescription="@string/left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/availability_ctx_level3_right"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"
                android:contentDescription="@string/right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <com.my.package.HorizontalListView
                android:id="@+id/availability_ctx_level3_list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/availability_ctx_level3_left"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/availability_ctx_level3_right" />

        </RelativeLayout >

    </LinearLayout>
```

My HorizontalListView class is fully working and extends `AdapterView<ListAdapter>`.

Is there a way to only display the arrow needed and how to move to next item in the list?

Thanks.

Regards.

Comment: Which implementation of HorizontalListView did you try ?

Comment: This one http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34

Comment: I've successfully scroll to right with that code: `drop1.setSelection(drop1.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1);` but I'm not able to left scroll. With I use `drop1.setSelection(drop1.getSelectedItemPosition() - 1);` nothing happens.

Comment: look at my comment on this forum (dev-smart), I achieved scrolling programatically

Comment: Thanks I tried something but it only works once, then I can use it anymore. Here is the code `int scroll = drop1.getScrollY() - px;`
    `drop1.scrollTo(scroll < 0 ? 0 : scroll);`

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but I think I made my code better by putting that in a runnabled that is delayed by a handler after 300 ms

Comment: Btw, the method setSelection is not implemented in the previous link I gave. Has anyone here done something with it?
`@Override
 public void setSelection(int position) {
  //TODO: implement
 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved my problem with a little hack:

```
    private int item_width = 70; // Width in pixel

    public void scrollLeft()
    {
        mNextX -= item_width;
        mScroller.fling(mNextX, 0, -50, 0, 0, mMaxX, 0, 0);
        requestLayout();
    }

    public void scrollRight()
    {
        mNextX += item_width;
        mScroller.fling(mNextX, 0, -50, 0, 0, mMaxX, 0, 0);
        requestLayout();
    }
```

If it can help someone...

Comment: Well, I put a listener on my arrow buttons and use the previous methods to scroll automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code belows into the HorizontalListView class, implement it on your action event; you can scroll your horizontalListView like what viewPager can do

```
/**
 * scrollLeft : scroll the list to left
 */
public void scrollToLeft() {
    mNextX -= getMeasuredWidth();
    mScroller.fling(mNextX, 0, -50, 0, 0, mMaxX, 0, 0);
    requestLayout();
}

/**
 * scrollRight : scroll the list to right
 */
public void scrollToRight() {
    mNextX += getMeasuredWidth();
    mScroller.fling(mNextX, 0, -50, 0, 0, mMaxX, 0, 0);
    requestLayout();
}
```